# .whl is not supported wheel on this platform Raspberrypi(B+)

Tags: python, pip, webrtc

I am trying to install ***webrtc*** for audio processing purpose on ***raspberrypi(B+)***.

I am using pip ***9.0.1*** from python ***2.7***

When I write the following command:

`pip install ./webrtc*.whl`

I get the following error:

`DoAwebrtc_audio_processing-0.0.1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_armv7l.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`

***Can you tell me what is the problem?***

Comment: Where did you get the wheel? Wheels are compiled for a specific platform. You should not need to specify a wheel - if the package is available for the Pi it will download the appropriate wheel (if available). PS B+ is ARM6 processor.

Comment: I am trying to run the code given on this link to find Direction of arrival:

https://github.com/SeeedDocument/ReSpeaker-4-Mic-Array-for-Raspberry-Pi/blob/master/ReSpeaker-4-Mic-Array-for-Raspberry-Pi.md

They are using this wheel `pip install ./webrtc*.whl              # install webrtc for DoA`

Comment: @Milliways can you please tell this wheel file is for which pi model???

Comment: The link seems rather vague, as is the link `webrtc*.whl` - the link in your question seems to be for ARM7 i.e. Pi2/3. The site mentions different Pi models, but gives no instructions for different models.